# Link External Library when using CMakeLists used by CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have build libmemcached.a and copied it to /usr/local/lib on my mac and I have tried all the following options to link libmemcached.a and yet get compile time errors that libmemcached/memcached.h is not found.

```
link_libraries (${libmemcached})
include_directories(SYSTEM ${libmemcached})
link_directories("/usr/local/lib")
find_package(libmemcached.a REQUIRED)
link_libraries`enter code here`(libmemcached.a)
find_library(RESULT libmemcached.a PATHS /usr/local/lib)
target_link_libraries(dnsa_pcl libmemcached.a)
```

It is a simple -L -l using MakeFile. Not sure what needs to be done to make this work using CMakeLists. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't just copy it somewhere, you should use the build system's install routine.

Comment: also, there's a typo in your code

Comment: It should not be `find_package(libmemcached.a REQUIRED)` since you are looking for a package not a static library. Maybe it should be `find_package(libmemcached REQUIRED)` but then there is there a finder for `libmemcached`

Comment: Also you want to find the library before link_libraries and include_directories or how are you setting `${libmemcached}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find specific/local files via CMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658850/how-to-find-specific-local-files-via-cmake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use so called imported library, like it's described in the official [documentation](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is a bit weird. I had to both set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to the directory that has the lib and also have include_directories() with the include folder of the source. For some reason, I was under the impression that the libmemcached.a had the header files as well.